key limes not ready to harvest by winter
Potted key lime on my patio is covered with small limes.  I live in Michigan and it will soon be time to bring the plant inside and limes are not ripe yet.  Will they continue to ripen inside in normal room temperature?

Are you aware that the Key Lime never gets bigger than a large grape? Must be why it's juiced for that pie.

Sure the limes will ripen indoors; as long as the tree is happy you'll have no problems.
